# why do i receive an errorcode when i RUN SQL on Db2

Tags: sql, db2

Please, can someone help me solve this issue i am with my IBM Db2 account. when i run SQL, it shows **[jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000** .  I have tried changing password, logging out and back in but its still the same.

Comment: Add more details on what you are doing. In general, your are using the wrong credentials. That results in this error message

Comment: The userid/password is on the Db2-server (not your workstation), so you have to change the password at the Db2-server side. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using to run SQL against Db2? How did you configure the connection in the tool? Are you able to connect to the Db2 before you ran the SQL?

Also, check if you use any special characters in your credentials for your Db2 account, if you do, try to avoid that.